# I2C in Raspbery Pi 3 using smbus

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, accelerometer, i2c, smbus

I'm trying to interface my accelerometer ADXL3458 to my Raspberry Pi 3 running in ubuntu mate. I have install all the necessary package require for the I2C communication. When I perform this command `i2cdetect -y 1` I get this results.[image]

Now I run this Python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smbus
import time
import math
from math import sin, cos, pi

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

print bus

ACC_ADRESS = 0x53

acc_x = 0.0
acc_y = 0.0
acc_z = 0.0


def writeACC (register, value):
    bus.write_byte_data(ACC_ADRESS, register, value)
    return -1

def readACC_byte ( addr):
    return bus.read_byte_data(ACC_ADRESS, addr)


def readACC_word (addr):
    LSB = bus.read_byte_data(ACC_ADRESS, addr)
    MSB = bus.read_byte_data(ACC_ADRESS, addr + 1)

    val = (MSB << 8) | LSB
    return val


def setupACC ():
    # Sleep mode
    writeACC(0x2D, 0)
    # Mesurement mode
    writeACC(0x2D, 8)
    # enable Autu sleep mode
    writeACC(0x2D, 16)

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        acc_x = readACC_word(0x32)
        acc_y = readACC_word(0x34)
        acc_z = readACC_word(0x36)

        print "Acc_x :\n", acc_x
        print "Acc_y :\n", acc_y
        print "Acc_z :\n", acc_z

        time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setupACC()
```

And I get this result in the oscilloscope[image]

This infer that my I2C communication is successful. But in the result that I'm printing shows no value in it 
[image]

Can please help with problem that I'm facing. Is it anything that I'm doing wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Auto sleep mode was should not active. Upon commenting 
`#writeACC(0x2D, 16)` 
is working fine.